# How to properly abort improper test case?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, automated-tests

I know you have `fail()` to mark that a test has failed under specific condition if used with `if` condition. However, it's my understanding that `fail()` is used to mark the failure of the assumption of the test, not the code of the test itself. For example, say I have `expectedFile` and `actualFile`, but if we don't have `expectedFile`, I want to abort the test case. I could:

```
if(expectedFile == null){
    fail()
}
```

But the logging would imply that it's what we are testing that's failing, not the test case itself. I was wondering if there is a separate way of indicating that the failure comes from the test case itself rather than from the unit that we are testing.

Comment: Yes, an exception that is not `AssertionError` will do.

Comment: @xiaofeng.li So is creating a custom exception such as "TestException" acceptable practice?

Comment: Usually you don't create a specific exception for this. Any exception that's not an `AssertionError` would be considered an error in the test code itself, not an error in the code being tested.

Comment: What is the point? If the test is failing because the files don't match, or because the file is missing entirely, either way a human is going to have to investigate why the test is failing.

Comment: @DavidConrad I loop through one directory and try to match that file with the file from another directory. If the first directory is empty, the test case ends without any exception since it doesn't enter the for-loop and JUnit passes the test, which is not the behavior I want. Basically, if the first directory is empty, it should not be a valid test case.

Comment: So, if the first directory is empty, throw a [`FileNotFoundException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html).

Comment: @DavidConrad but then what if the unit we are testing also throws FileNotFoundException? We wouldn't know which one is throwing it

Comment: Is that even possible? Anyway, the stack trace would show you if the exception was thrown in the test itself or the unit under test. But if you're that worried (remember, if the test fails a human is going to have to look into why and where it's failing), create your own unique exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Assume.assumeNotNull(...)`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html#assumeNotNull(java.lang.Object...)) method which would throw an `AssumptionViolatedException` for you.  Something like:

```
import static org.junit.Assume.assumeNotNull;

// later in the code
void someMethod() {
   assumeNotNull(expectedFile, actualFile);
   // Rest of code goes here
}
```

An alternative might be to use [`Objects.requireNonNull(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-), which will throw a `NullPointerException` if argument is `null`.

Comment: This is perfect. It seems like `Assume` is specifically designed for the test case itself

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you don't simply use  `assertEquals()` since if `actualFile` is null it fails with the error message:

```
expected "the expected file name" but was NULL
```

which is quite easy to understand...